# Comment on posts Django

Tags: python, django

I want that users comment on posts, for now users need to redirect to another page to comment which is 'add_comment_to_post.html' and I still get error when submitting the form at this line 'return redirect('blog:index', post.pk)' 
'NoReverseMatch at /blog/post/70/comment/'

views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
        template_name = 'blog/index.html'
        context_object_name = 'posts'
        def get_queryset(self):
            return Post.objects.all()



def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.post = post
        comment.save()
        return redirect('blog:index', post.pk)
else:
    form = CommentForm()
return render(request, 'blog/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form})
```

and here the form within 'blog/index.html'

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.textc }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Send</button>
    </form>
```

form.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('textc',)
```

the urls.py

```
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/$', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
```

Comment: From where are you calling add_comment_to_post()?

Comment: I think I am not calling it, how do I do that ?

Comment: Then I would suggest learning a bit more about Django views. You can refactor the above code by using two separate methodes: get(self, request, *args, **kwargs) and post(self, request, *args, **kwargs). Put your if request.method=='POST' code in the post() method, and the rest in the get() method. Get() en post() are view methods which are available for all views.View subclasses.

Comment: Actually, there is a lot more wrong to do exactly what you would like to achieve. Do you want to display the comment form for every single Post object in the database?

Comment: yes I'd like to display the comment form ( like in facebook )
I made some change and i just edit in the question, I made some progress but still can't get it.

Comment: i just realised what's going on, the post.id is 70 but in reality when I check it from admin it's 56! So how do I set post.id to start from zero ?

Comment: If you did not manually set a different primary key field, then post.id and post.pk should be identical. There should be no difference between what you are seeing and the admin.

Comment: But I need some more information, because I am still uncertain to what exactly you are trying to do. Do you want visitors to be able to post on the ListView (as you are doing now) or on some DetailView? If you want them to be able to post on the ListView then you will have a lot of comment forms, and it would be a lot easier using a custom template tag.

Comment: I just want logged-in users be able to comment on posts

Comment: I understand, but do you want them to be able to comment on a page which shows only one post (= detail view), or a page which shows every post (= list view)?

Comment: A page which shows every post

Comment: So you need 1 form for every post available. Every single HTML form tag also needs its own action attribute, which will be the url you are showing from your urls.py file. 
In your template you should have a for loop iterating over all post objects, and adding the form with the action attribute for each of them. But now there is not a single form present in your template, because the IndexView is being rendered and that does not have a form at this point.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help !